# Edit the url sent in confirmation email dj_rest_auth

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

When I register a new user the confirmation email sent in the email template contains the url of backend but i need to handle that in forntend. Anyone know how to edit that email template of dj_rest_auth by jazzband?

The email template is:

> Hello from example.com!
>
> You're receiving this e-mail because user Pinon has given yours as an
> e-mail address to connect their account.
>
> To confirm this is correct, go to
> http://localhost:8000/auth/registration/account-confirm-email/Nw:1kO3gI:PQDfxEOyklUYIxpjNN_011ZxGQYPJRdNomzzOFjtXA0/
>
> Thank you from example.com! example.com

But i need it to be like this:

> Hello from example.com!
>
> You're receiving this e-mail because user Pinon has given yours as an
> e-mail address to connect their account.
>
> To confirm this is correct, go to
> http://localhost:3000/account-confirm-email/Nw:1kO3gI:PQDfxEOyklUYIxpjNN_011ZxGQYPJRdNomzzOFjtXA0/
>
> Thank you from example.com! example.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this thing is handled by django_allauth package. So you have to do so as they suggested in their (django_allauth) [documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-email)

So I have created my dir like this: templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt then added this code to the file:

```
{% load account %}{% user_display user as user_display %}{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!

You're receiving this e-mail because user {{ user_display }} has given your e-mail address to register an account on {{ site_domain }}.

To confirm this is correct, <a href="http://localhost:3000/auth/account/confirm/email/{{ key }}" target="_blank">Click here.</a>
{% endblocktrans %}
{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Thank you from {{ site_name }}!
{{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

That

> {{ key }}

is the main thing to find .